# What's the approach to coding navigation driven by a universal link?

Tags: ios-universal-links

My app is called to handle a universal link, but I'm a little unsure how to set my app to the desired *view controller* that is required by each universal link.

my app structure is

`root vc -> tabbed vc -> page vc` (with 4 pages)

The app could well be in a different 'branch' as required by a universal link or it could be displaying the exact vc required and just needs its content refreshing

how do I go about cleanly implementing a system to back-out of a current navigation end point and go to the correct vc?

The app supports Apple's Restoration framework. Does Apple iOS have another framework I can leverage?

Answer (score 1):

For someone to have clicked on one of your universal links they will have had to either background or close your app. When the app becomes active, the entry point will be in the AppDelegate class: the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions fucntion, if this is a cold start, otherwise the continueUserActivity function.

The easiest thing to do is to simply push a new ViewController from within these functions (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or continueUserActivity).

If you do need to close ViewControllers that were open in the previous session this is something you can do in the same code block that you are using to present the proper ViewController.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For a simply app I think your approach works but as an app grows it seems odd to have so much logic about app navigation here. For now I fire off a message to my root vc and it then calls he necessary class to handle the first stage of navigation. If there are further steps required then then the next is handled and then the next class is called.